# How to check if an item is followed by another item in a list? C#

Tags: c#, list

I have these names:

```
Sean
Winnie
Brian Amy
Samir
Joe Bethany
Bruno Anna Matthew Lucas
Gabriel Martha Philip
Andre
Danielle
Leo Cinthia
Paula
Mary Jane
Anderson
Priscilla
Regis Julianna Arthur
Mark Marina
Alex Andrea
```

The exercise says, that the names separated by a space in a line, cannot give gifts to each other. Like Leo can't give presents to Cinthia, Joe can't give for Bethany etc.

So I am looking for a code that I can use to check that, if I have a list and the lines are imported into that list, then I want to check if there is a certain string (like Leo is followed by Cinthia) followed by the space, then those two people can't give presents to each other.

So far I am here:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace SecretSanta
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StreamReader File = new StreamReader("SSfile.txt");
            List<string> Names = new List<string>();
            string line = File.ReadLine();

            while (line != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(line);
                line = File.ReadLine();
                Names.Add(line);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And what's your question?

Comment: So i am looking for a code that i can use to check that, if i have a list and the lines are imported into that list, then i want to check if there is a certain string (like Leo is followed by Cinthia) followed by the space, then those two people can't give presents to each other.

Comment: Lots of things you could do here, but here's a quick snippet that might point you in the right direction: `var names = line.Split(" ", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`.

Comment: You can use method Split when take an item from the list and check if it exist two names. In that case you only must complete the if sentence

Comment: `List<string[]> names = File.ReadLines(filename).Select(line => line.Split()).ToList();`

    `string name1 = "Gabriel";`
    `string name2 = "Philip";`

    `bool canGiveGift = !names.Any(x => x.Contains(name1) && x.Contains(name2));`

Comment: @Eser I'm sorry but visual studio detects some errors in that, could you edit it somehow?

Comment: @JohnDale I compiled it before posting, you may be missing `System.Linq` namespace

Comment: @Eser i'm not missing System.Linq i don't know what may be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
 class Program
    {
        static Dictionary<string, List<string>> Names = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StreamReader File = new StreamReader("SSfile.txt");
            string line = File.ReadLine();
            while (line != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(line);
                line = File.ReadLine();
                var names = line.Split(" ", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                Names.Add(names[0], names.Skip(1).ToList());
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static bool canGive(giver, givee)
        {
           return Names[giver].Any(item => item == givee);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Good answer, though `Dictionary` is an overkill. `KeyValuePair` collection is much more suitable for this case. You'r answer has O(n) complexity which is great, but if you replace the dictionary with a simple `List<KeyValuePair>` , you'd get even better results.

Answer (score -2):

The thing is, that it wouldn't work this way in my understanding of your problem.

You have a list with *{'Sean', 'Winnie', ... 'Joe', Bethany'}*
So if you check if Joe is followed by Bethany and then disallow him to give gifts to Bethany, you would also forbid Sean to give gifts to Winnie...
I think you need more than a single list to achieve this functionality.
You could maybe use a List containing Lists which contain the people in one row
e.g. *{{'Sean'}, {'Winnie'}, ..., {'Joe', Bethany'}}*

Hope I understood your problem correctly.

Comment: I think you understood my problem. Is that called a two dimensional list?

Comment: Much, much simpler to simply use one `List<string>` and then use `String.Split()` to see if there's more than one name in each entry.  Using multiple lists or nested lists complicates it unnecessarily.

Comment: @JohnDale your question does not suggest that this is the case.